# create groups from data with duplicates such that each group has a duplicate represented once

Tags: r

I have a sequencing run with ~3000 samples. The samples were initially tagged and amplified by PCR in duplicate. The tags used range from Tag1 to Tag26.

Tag1-Tag13 were used for pair 1 and Tag14-Tag26 were used for pair 2. The tags are re-used to allow samples to be pooled.

The pooling process will involve mixing samples with tags 1-26 into the first group, the next samples from 1-26 into the second group and so on. It's good to note that sometimes some tags are missing because that respective sample failed to amplify.

I need to have these groups on paper first - before proceeding to the lab.

Here's a snapshot of the samples before being grouped. (Note that `Tag01` to `Tag05` are used for `TagA` and `Tag06` to  `Tag10` for `TagB` in the sample dataset.)

```
preGroup <- structure(list(SampleID = 1:19, TagA = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("Tag01", "Tag02", "Tag03", "Tag04", "Tag05"), class = "factor"), 
    TagB = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Tag06", 
    "Tag07", "Tag08", "Tag09", "Tag10"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

```
   SampleID  TagA  TagB
1         1 Tag03 Tag10
2         2 Tag04 Tag06
3         3 Tag05 Tag07
4         4 Tag03 Tag09
5         5 Tag04 Tag10
6         6 Tag05 Tag06
7         7 Tag01 Tag06
8         8 Tag02 Tag07
9         9 Tag03 Tag08
10       10 Tag01 Tag10
11       11 Tag02 Tag06
12       12 Tag03 Tag07
13       13 Tag01 Tag08
14       14 Tag03 Tag09
15       15 Tag04 Tag10
16       16 Tag01 Tag07
17       17 Tag02 Tag08
18       18 Tag03 Tag09
19       19 Tag04 Tag10
```

and here's the same data after grouped...

```
postGroup <- structure(list(SampleID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 7L), TagA = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L), .Label = c("Tag01", "Tag02", "Tag03", "Tag04", "Tag05"
), class = "factor"), TagB = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Tag06", 
"Tag07", "Tag08", "Tag09", "Tag10"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 7L), .Label = c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5", 
"group6", "group7"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

```
   SampleID  TagA  TagB  group
1         1 Tag03 Tag10 group1
2         2 Tag04 Tag06 group1
3         3 Tag05 Tag07 group1
4         4 Tag03 Tag09 group2
5         5 Tag04 Tag10 group2
6         6 Tag05 Tag06 group2
7         8 Tag02 Tag07 group2
8         9 Tag03 Tag08 group3
9        10 Tag01 Tag10 group3
10       11 Tag02 Tag06 group3
11       12 Tag03 Tag07 group4
12       13 Tag01 Tag08 group4
13       14 Tag03 Tag09 group5
14       15 Tag04 Tag10 group5
15       16 Tag01 Tag07 group5
16       17 Tag02 Tag08 group5
17       18 Tag03 Tag09 group6
18       19 Tag04 Tag10 group6
19        7 Tag01 Tag06 group7
```

I'm looking for an R script that can create these groups because we're used to working with less than 50 samples and we would create the groups manually, however, the scale of this task is overwhelming...

Finally, because the samples are in the 1000s, it'll be better if the code can try as much as possible to keep the samples in their original order in the sense that sample 1 is closer to say sample 50 than it is to sample 500 to enable an easy sequential process of retrieval in the lab (I hope am making sense here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to group his samples, so that

1. each group contains as many samples as possible,
2. each group contains only one distinct element of `TagA` and one distinct element of `TagB`,
3. samples are kept in the original order as far as possible.

The approach below works iteratively by placing all samples in one group, then looking for any duplicates (from top to bottom) which are placed in the next group. This will continue until no group with duplicates is found.

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is used here because it is able to update *by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole object.

```
library(data.table)
grouped <- as.data.table(preGroup)[order(SampleID)][, group := 1L][]
max_grp <- 1L
while (any(grouped[, anyDuplicated(TagA) | anyDuplicated(TagB), by = group]$V1)) {
  max_grp <- max_grp + 1L
  dups <- duplicated(grouped, by = c("group", "TagA")) | 
    duplicated(grouped, by = c("group", "TagB"))
  grouped[dups, group := max_grp][]
  stopifnot(max_grp <= nrow(grouped)) # just to prevent infinite looping
}
grouped
```

> ```
>     SampleID  TagA  TagB group
>  1:        1 Tag03 Tag10     1
>  2:        2 Tag04 Tag06     1
>  3:        3 Tag05 Tag07     1
>  4:        4 Tag03 Tag09     2
>  5:        5 Tag04 Tag10     2
>  6:        6 Tag05 Tag06     2
>  7:        7 Tag01 Tag06     3
>  8:        8 Tag02 Tag07     2
>  9:        9 Tag03 Tag08     3
> 10:       10 Tag01 Tag10     4
> 11:       11 Tag02 Tag06     4
> 12:       12 Tag03 Tag07     4
> 13:       13 Tag01 Tag08     5
> 14:       14 Tag03 Tag09     5
> 15:       15 Tag04 Tag10     5
> 16:       16 Tag01 Tag07     6
> 17:       17 Tag02 Tag08     6
> 18:       18 Tag03 Tag09     6
> 19:       19 Tag04 Tag10     6
> ```

Note that this result has one group less than OP's hand-picked `postGroup` which contains a seventh group with only one sample.

We can perform some checks to verify that condition 2. is fulfilled:

```
grouped[, anyDuplicated(TagA), by = group]
```

> ```
>    group V1
> 1:     1  0
> 2:     2  0
> 3:     3  0
> 4:     4  0
> 5:     5  0
> 6:     6  0
> ```

```
grouped[, anyDuplicated(TagB), by = group]
```

> ```
>    group V1
> 1:     1  0
> 2:     2  0
> 3:     3  0
> 4:     4  0
> 5:     5  0
> 6:     6  0
> ```

#### Note

This might be not the most efficient approach and/or implementation. However, I wanted to have something at hand which delivers the expected result before starting to think about optimisation.

Comment: Thank you @Uwe, amazing!! especially trying to maintain the order of samples as much as possible. Quick question, what if a user wouldn't mind the order of samples (this scenario is foreseeable)...how would you achieve that...?

Comment: If the goal is to minimize the number of overall groups, this could lead to general optimisation problem (perhaps, something like the "knapsack problem").

Comment: I understand the need to minimize the number of overall groups. However, as mentioned in my previous comment, the change in conditions leads to a different question. Therefore, I respectfully suggest that you post a new question which stresses the need for minimizing the number of groups. Thank you.

Comment: Noted, thank you again @Uwe..